# Does cooldown reduction influence item abilities?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm asking if my cooldown reduction influences the cooldown time of my item's click abilities.

Can someone explain me how it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, your [cooldown reduction (CDR)](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cooldown_reduction) items will not effect your item cooldowns.

> Cooldown reduction does not apply on item active abilities such as
>   that of  Deathfire Grasp or item passive effects with cooldowns such
>   as that of  Guardian Angel. Most sources of cooldown reduction also
>   does not apply on summoner spells unless specifically stated, e.g. the
>   unique enchantment effect of  Distortion for boots or the unique
>   passive, Aid, of  Eleisa's Miracle. Cooldown Reduction does not apply
>   to an Innate Ability [the passive abilities of Champions] of any kind.

However, you can get the utility tree mastery [Artificer](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Artificer) to reduce the cooldown times of your item's active effects by by 7.5/15%. This can make a pretty significant difference on some of the longer cooldowns.

[image]

Source: [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Artificer)